# Initializer requirement 'init(json:)' can only be satisfied by a `required` initializer in the definition of non-final class 'UIColor'

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm trying to write an extension to satisfy a protocol in an extension like so:

```
extension UIColor: JSONRepresentable {
    convenience init?(json: Any) {
        guard let colourArray = json as? [CGFloat] else {
            print("json was not an array of CGFloats")
            return nil
        }
    
        self.init(
            red: colourArray[0],
            green: colourArray[1],
            blue: colourArray[2],
            alpha: colourArray[3]
        )
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Initializer requirement 'init(json:)' can only be satisfied by a required initializer in the definition of non-final class 'UIColor'.
```

If I add a `required` keyword, I get this error

```
'required' initializer must be declared directly in class 'UIColor' (not in an extension).
```

Is there a reason for this or any way to work around it?

**Edit:** Just to be clear, here's the protocol

```
protocol JSONRepresentable {
    init?(json: Any)
}
```

Comment: Which swift version are you using, in Swift4 your code compiles fine for me ? Though I had to remove the `JSONRepresentable` conformance, since I'm testing in a playground, but that should make a difference

Comment: I'm also using Swift4. I've just clarified the protocol requirements. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @DávidPásztor That's kind of the crucial part there. When implementing initializer from a protocol, `required` must be there.

Comment: Right, but when when I add that, I get the second error: `'required' initializer must be declared directly in class 'UIColor' (not in an extension)`. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: Why don't you create a `struct Color: Codable`, add those 4 properties (red, green, blue and alpha) and just add a computed property to return a UIColor from it? Instead of initializing it from an array of CGFloats just use a dictionary `let json = """
{"red": 1.0, "green": 0.0, "blue": 0.0, "alpha": 1.0}
"""`

Comment: Thanks, Leo. I might end up doing that. I'd still like to know why my code won't compile though. I don't think I'm doing anything especially unusual.

Comment: Can I post the struct solution?

Comment: Be my guest. I think it might be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 5):

```
struct Color: Codable {
    let red, green, blue, alpha: CGFloat
}

extension Color {
    var uiColor: UIColor { return UIColor(color: self) }
    var cgColor: CGColor { return uiColor.cgColor }
    var ciColor: CIColor { return CIColor(color: uiColor) }
    var data: Data { return try! JSONEncoder().encode(self) }
}

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(color: Color) {
        self.init(red: color.red, green: color.green, blue: color.blue, alpha: color.alpha)
    }
    var color: Color {
        let color = CIColor(color: self)
        return Color(red: color.red, green: color.green, blue: color.blue, alpha: color.alpha)
    }
}
extension Data {
    var string: String {
        return String(data: self, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing

```
let json = """
{"red": 0.5, "green": 0.0, "blue": 0.0, "alpha": 1.0}
"""

if let color = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Color.self, from: Data(json.utf8)) {
    print(color)                  // "Color(red: 0.5, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)\n"
    print(color.uiColor)          // "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.5 0 0 1\n
    print(color.data)         // "40 bytes\n"
    print(color.data.string)  // "{"red":0.5,"alpha":1,"blue":0,"green":0}\n"
}

let redColor = UIColor.red.color
let jsonData = redColor.data.string  // "{"red":1,"alpha":1,"blue":0,"green":0}"
```

---

---

If you need to work with your array of CGFloats you can override JSON Encoder and Decoder initializers:

```
extension Color {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        red   = try container.decode(CGFloat.self)
        green = try container.decode(CGFloat.self)
        blue  = try container.decode(CGFloat.self)
        alpha = try container.decode(CGFloat.self)
    }
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(red)
        try container.encode(green)
        try container.encode(blue)
        try container.encode(alpha)
    }
}
```

---

Testing

```
let values: [CGFloat] = [0.5,0.0,0.0,1.0]
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values) // 11 bytes
let json = jsonData.string   // "[0.5,0,0,1]"

do {
    let color = try JSONDecoder().decode(Color.self, from: jsonData)
    print(color)                  // "Color(red: 0.5, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)\n"
    print(color.uiColor)          // "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.5 0 0 1\n
    print(color.data)                                  // "11 bytes\n"
    print(color.data.string)                           // "[0.5,0,0,1]\n"
    let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(color)  // 11 bytes
    print(encodedData == jsonData)                     // true
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `UIColor` (and all of its descendants) `Codable` and use embedded JSONEncoder/Decoder to handle it.

```
import UIKit

extension Encodable where Self: UIColor {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var r, g, b, a: CGFloat
        (r, g, b, a) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        try container.encode([r,g,b,a])
    }
}

extension Decodable where Self: UIColor {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let components = try container.decode([CGFloat].self)
        self = Self.init(red: components[0], green: components[1], blue: components[2], alpha: components[3])
    }
}

extension UIColor: Codable { }
```

Test it

```
class ColorDescendant: UIColor { }
let testColor = ColorDesedant.green

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let colorAsJSON = try encoder.encode(testColor)
print(String(data: colorAsJSON, encoding: .utf8)!)
let uiColor = try? decoder.decode(ColorDesedant.self, from: colorAsJSON)
uiColor! == testColor
```

Answer (score 0):

The message I get for **this** code is (Swift 5.0)

```
Initializer requirement 'init(json:)' can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in non-final class 'MyColor'
```

Trying replacing

```
extension UIColor: JSONRepresentable
```

with

```
class MyColor: UIColor, JSONRepresentable
```

, I've the same message.

It means that the `MyColor` class can't be extended 'as this', but if you use the mentioned `required` keyword, all subclasses would be mandatory to implement this initializer.

For example, adding `final` to the class (=> `final class MyColor: UIColor, JSONRepresentable`) you can forgot the '`required`' initializer, because you explicitly mention that there will never be subclasses for '`MyColor`'.
It's nice, it's the principle for protocols, to says (to other developers, but to you too) that some functions are required or not.