# Making UIColor Codable - conforming to protocol 'Encodable'

Tags: swift, encoding, uicolor

I'm having difficulty encoding and loading transformable color data from a plist that previously loaded without difficulty from code.

In an extension of UIColor, I've a limited number of available colours in a struct plus my encoder and decoder.

```
extension UIColor
{
struct Words
{
    static let verb = UIColor(netHex: 0xff0000)
    static let noun = UIColor.blue
    static let subject = UIColor(netHex: 0x0000ff)
    static let object = UIColor(netHex: 0x1e5900)
    static let indirectObject = UIColor(netHex: 0x369d01)
    static let genitive = UIColor(netHex: 0x783f04)
    static let article = UIColor(netHex: 0xff6500)
    static let adjective = UIColor(netHex: 0x9900ff)
    static let adverb = UIColor(netHex: 0xff00ff)
    static let generic = UIColor(netHex: 0x70747a)
}

class func color(data:Data) -> UIColor? {
    return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? UIColor
}

func encode() -> Data? {
    return try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false)
}
}
```

**In my code model** (this works), I simply defined the color's text value:

```
var color1: String?
... 
color1 = subject // etc
```

And in a method, the encoded data is loaded into the DB:

```
let myColorData = myColor1.encode()
```

And then in a collection view cellForItemAt indexPath, I can access the color data, which I use to attribute text (not shown).

```
let color1 = UIColor.color(data: cellData.color1 as! Data)
```

The problem occurs when, instead of loading the data from code, I load it from a pList. The data seems to load into Core Data, but the app crashes anyway, with an error:

- Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x108cc0560) to 'UIColor'

I think this means UIColor is not being encoded(?), although it does seem to load something 'blob' into the DB.

If I follow advice from [Make UIColor Codable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928153/make-uicolor-codable), and similar, but I keep getting the error.

- Referencing instance method 'encode(to:)' on 'Optional' requires that 'UIColor' conform to 'Encodable'.

I guess I need to make my struct Words: Codable, but I'm not sure if that is true, nor what is required to do this.

Could someone please advise what I need to do in this case how to make UIColor encodable in the way I need it to?

Comment: You can’t. You need to create your own color structure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46522572/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want `UIColor` additionally conform to `Codable`? It conforms already to `NSSecureCoding` so it's serializable to `Data` by default.

And even with your implementation you can encode a color

```
let encoded = UIColor.Words.adverb.encode()!
```

and decode it

```
let color = UIColor.color(data: encoded)
```

And particularly in Core Data you can use computed properties to transform a supported type to an unsupported and vice versa.

My recommedation for Core Data is to save the color as `Int32` (the hex representation) or as (hex) `String`

---

This is an implementation I'm using in Core Data, an extension to convert the color to a hex string

```
extension UIColor {

    private func float2String(_ float : CGFloat) -> String {
        return String(format:"%02X", Int(round(float * 255)))
    }

    var hex : String {
        var red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: nil)
        return "#" + float2String(red) + float2String(green) + float2String(blue)
    }

    convenience init(hex : String) {
        let hex = hex.hasPrefix("#") ? String(hex.dropFirst()) : hex
        if hex.count == 6, hex.range(of: "[^0-9A-Fa-f]", options: .regularExpression) == nil {
            let chars = Array(hex)
            let numbers = stride(from: 0, to: chars.count, by: 2).map() {
                CGFloat(strtoul(String(chars[$0 ..< min($0 + 2, chars.count)]), nil, 16))
            }
            self.init(red: numbers[0] / 255, green: numbers[1] / 255, blue: numbers[2] / 255, alpha: 1.0)
        } else {
            self.init(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

and the relevant part of the `NSManagedObject` subclass

```
@NSManaged public var hexColor: String


var color : UIColor {
    get { return UIColor(hex: hexColor) }
    set { hexColor = newValue.hex }
}
```